# modify the IP address of a URL from a TEXTBOX C#

Tags: c#

I am looking for a solution to modify the IP address of a URL from a TEXTBOX.
I would like to replace this
I would like to validate the replacement of the ip with a button.
Thanks for your help

```
private const string Url = "axrtsphttp://192.168.0.119/axis-media/media.amp?videocodec=h264";
```

I tried several methods resembling that but I have two error generated CS0501, CS0236,

here is the last test

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e);

string IP = textBox1.text;

private const string Url = "axrtsphttp://"+IP+"/axis-media/media.amp?videocodec=h264";
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Check [Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(..)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.iswellformeduristring?view=netframework-4.8#System_Uri_IsWellFormedUriString_System_String_System_UriKind_) and [Uri.TryCreate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.trycreate?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Uri.TryCreate);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.2);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8) functions.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question. Then [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Answer (score 0):

Remove const keyword from the string that you are assigning a dynamic address, or use the below code snippet:

```
private string Url = "axrtsphttp://{0}/axis-media/media.amp?videocodec=h264";
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string IP = textBox1.text;
   Url = string.Format(Url, IP);
}
```